# Many Booleans On Two Tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, boolean

Using Rails 2.1 and Mysql.

I have a `corporation model`, which `has_many companies`

And of course the `company model`, which `belongs_to corporation`

I need to add quite a few boolean columns to these two tables, but this feels really wrong. Each table will have the same booleans, and we would be checking first the company to see if it's true, and then corporation. So, the options I can see are these:

- Add the boolean values to each table. I suppose this is simplest but feels really redundant.
- Create an extra table called something like "boolean_options", which would belong_to company and corporation. Each boolean is added to this table, and then connect to the appropriate model(s).
- Use something like the [has_many_booleans gem](https://github.com/janlelis/has_many_booleans), which means I add one column (boolean) to each table and handle the data in my code. This seems like it would be the least obvious solution, but feels more elegant to me, especially when it comes time to add more booleans to these tables.

What is the best way to handle booleans that will appear across multiple tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may depend more on your overall concept than anything else. For each true/false bit of data, ask yourself how closely linked it is to the essence of the model. How often will each bit be referenced in model instances, or used in searches. Those that are closely linked may belong in the model; the ones that are less so may be better grouped in other tables.

**Example**: In the real world, a corporation is a type of company and shares many of the `Company` attributes; these attributes could be stored in the `Company` table, perhaps with an `is_a_corporation` flag.

Where corporations have unique attributes, such as the ability to own companies, these functions and attributes should be in the `Corporation` model.

**Booleans as Bits:** I don't think there is anything wrong with having many boolean attributes in a model, but I agree that it seems inelegant to have all those boolean columns in the table. I checked out the `has_many_booleans` gem, which does offer some interesting opportunities for *simulating* bitwise operations and masks which, coming from the world of embedded software, makes a lot of sense to me.

Checking around, I discovered that **Postgresql** (my db of choice) offers the **bitstring** datatype and provides a plethora of *actual* bitwise operations on as many bits as you want, using just one column for all your booleans, which seems incredibly cool to me. The downside is you'd have to configure the column and and perform the operations in native SQL.

Comment: I did end up making a seperate "invoice_options" table, as I had about 12 booleans that are going to be shared between multiple tables, but are not going to be used often, and just make more sense to have separated out.
Corporations and companies are poorly named (but entrenched in the companies' lingo so can't really be changed); they are really more like companies and branches. Corporations is just a way to group companies.